# Grails Plugin dependencies

Tags: grails, plugins, dependencies

When creating a plugin that depends on other plugins, you specify these dependencies in the config of the plugin via the  `dependsOn` map.

What I want to know is if these plugins are downloaded automatically when you run install-plugin command?? 
If not, how can it be set up to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how it works in 1.2 and 1.3. In 2.0 however you'll want to configure dependencies in the `plugins` section of `BuildConfig.groovy` since `dependsOn` doesn't populate the pom file and that's what's used for dependency management in 2.0.

1.3 can also work with dependencies in BuildConfig.groovy, but 1.2 and earlier cannot. I think it's safe to assume that there aren't many users still on 1.2 or earlier, but if you need to support older versions you can just include instructions for them to explicitly install the required dependencies before installing your plugin.

Comment: Thanks Burt, this helped a tonne!

Comment: @Burt-beckwith - Thanks for clarifying, I was under impression that plugins specified in dependsOn will get downloaded automatically always. Is it documented anywhere that grails 2.x doesnt work this way ?