# Is there a Grails "plugin loaded"/"all plugins loaded" event?

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, grails-plugin

I am building a Grails plugin which will schedule jobs using the [quartz plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/quartz).  I am able to schedule jobs using the `static triggers` section, and the jobs run just fine.  But I also want to dynamically schedule jobs using the [Job.schedule method](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-quartz/guide/triggers.html), and when I call this method from a bootstrap, I get the following error: `No signature of method: static TransmitterRenameJob.schedule() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String)`.

Why is my job (which is the exact same job I am scheduling statically) lacking the schedule method?  Where should I put code to dynamically schedule my job?

**EDIT:**

On further research, it appears that the Quartz plugin is not loading till after the bootstrap runs, so the schedule method has not yet been injected.  At what point in my code can I be guaranteed that all plugins have loaded?  Is there a plugin loaded event to which I can subscribe?

Comment: That's a very different question. Will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704828/grails-plugin-dependencies